# Opening/reading an excel file in r

Tags: r, excel, readxl

I am having trouble opening/reading excel files that I download from the website of the Australian Bureau of Statistics using readxl.

I've [downloaded Table 12](http://www.abs.gov.au/AUSSTATS/abs@.nsf/DetailsPage/6202.0Jun%202018?OpenDocument) from the website but when I go to read the sheets of the workbook in `r` I get an error message:

```
library(readxl)    
excel_sheets(path = "C:/Users/Name/Documents/downloaded_file.xls")

"Error in xls_sheets(path) : Failed to open C:/Users/Name/Documents/downloaded_file.xls".
```

In previous versions of `readxl` I have had no trouble reading these files into `r` but I've recently updated my readxl version, after a hiatus of several months, and now it doesn't work.

I have tried to download the file using the `download.file` function taking care to set `mode = wb` but that makes no difference to being able to access the data in the workbook either.

Grateful for any pointers.

Comment: The file is a [*"Composite Document File V2 Document"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_File_Binary_Format), so it contains "streams" other than normal excel data. Sounds like someone did some "advanced authoring" on or near this file :-). I'm not familiar with tools in R that read it, nor any (non-R) tools that might separate the streams for you.

Comment: Thanks for that @r2evans. How did you work that out?

Comment: Downloaded it and ran `file 6202001.xls`, which reported the format as such. I haven't tried any of the other files on the same page, so it's possible it's just a one-off problem that staff accidentally dorked when handling the files. If you have a mechanism to ask them about it, perhaps they can regenerate or fix the file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried other packages. If I download the file manually and read it with `xlsx` it works for me. Is below ouptut what you need or am I missing something?

```
library("xlsx")
# there is certainly a better (faster) way to get the sheet number
n_sheets =  length(getSheets(loadWorkbook("6202012.xls")))
# if you know which sheet to load, reading the sheet works for me...
df = read.xlsx("6202012.xls", 2)
df[1:3, 1:3]
#            NA. Employed.total....Persons....Australia.. Employed.total....Persons....Australia...1
# 1        Unit                                      000                                        000
# 2 Series Type                                    Trend                        Seasonally Adjusted
# 3   Data Type                                    STOCK                                      STOCK
```

Answer (score 0):

It Works on Windows:

```
library(readxl)    
excel_sheets(path = "C:/Users/Name/Documents/downloaded_file.xls")
data<-readxl::read_excel(path = ""C:/Users/Name/Documents/downloaded_file.xls"",sheet = "Data1")
```